# How append to an array in a collection of documents using Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

Lets say I have a collection of `User`s. Each `user` has a history which is an array of `Event`s. I want to add an event to each `user`'s history, but each event will be unique.

How can I use Morphia to bulk-update the User's collection? Here is some pseudo-code:

```
List<User> users = datastore.find(....);
Set<Event> newEvents = createEvents(users);//events contains a reference the the users that are part of the event.

datastore.update(/*add event to history of user if user is part of event */);
```

I figure I could loop through the events and do an update on the users manually, but a bulk-update operation should be much more efficient.

Here is a sample before and after shot of 2 users:

```
//before
{
  _id: "user0001",
  history: [ "event0342" ]
},
{
  _id: "user0002",
  history: [ "event4521" ]
}

//after
{
  _id: "user0001",
  history: [ "event0342", "event4764" ]
},
{
  _id: "user0002",
  history: [ "event4521", "event5312" ]
}
```

So this implies that there were 2 events created: 4764 and 5312. User0001 was part of event4764 and user2 was part of event 5312.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your history class, and what is exactly expected ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona Sorry, history is just an array of events. Ill edit to make more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry it's still hard to understand... It's just an array of events, ok, but how is it stored/mapped ? It's a field canned history in "user" ? And you want to add newEvents to all users you peviously retrieved ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona I updated with a sample before and after

Comment: Ok, it's clear now ! Last part I don't get, is if you want to add all events contained in newEvents to each user ?

Comment: @MateoBarahona No. Each event has a list of attendees as part of it (I represented it as a string in the example for simplicities sake, but actually its an object. You can just think of the history field as a reference to the object id). Events should only be added to the history of users who were part of the event.

Comment: Ok, so I think basically you can't do that, neither with native Mongo nor Morphia. To add an event (or many events), you can use `$addToSet` in native mongo, or their equivalents in Morphia : `add()` and `addAll()` with last param being "false". But in one update operation you can't go and match events with the users.

Comment: @MateoBarahona Thats what I was afraid of :(

Comment: Yes... So loop through users, retrieved events for each one and do an update with $addToSet really seems the best option for me.